# Async SharePoint Calls In CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, csom

I am currently running one call to one Sharepoint site to get data, then when it completes, running a call to a second Sharepoint site to get data.

I am thinking there must be a way to make both calls simeltaneously and get the data and speed up the process.  This is my current syntax (most of it) - how could I change this to speed up the process of querying two different sharepoint sites?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var spvalues1 = CaptureSharePointData();
    var spvalues22 = CaptureSharePointData1();
}
struct SPData
{
    public string x;
    public string y;
    public string z;
    public string zz;
}

struct SPData1
{
    public string l;
    public string m;
    public string n;
    public string o;
}

private static SPData CaptureSharePointData()
{
    string a = null;
    string b = null;
    string c = null;
    string d = null;

    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(URL1))
    {
        var web = ctx.Web;

        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(Site1);
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("");

        var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

        ctx.Load(listItemCollection, eachItem => eachItem.Include(item => item, item => .....));

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach(ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
        {
          a = 
          b = 
          c = 
          d = 
        }
        var spvalues1 = new SPData
        {
            x = a,
            y = b,
            z = c,
            zz = d
        };
        return spvalues1;
    }
}

private static SPData1 CaptureSharePointData1()
{
    string a = null;
    string b = null;
    string c = null;
    string d = null;

    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(URL2))
    {
        var web = ctx.Web;

        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(Site2);
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("");

        var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

        ctx.Load(listItemCollection, eachItem => eachItem.Include(item => item, item => .....));

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach(ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
        {
          a = 
          b = 
          c = 
          d = 
        }
        var spvalues22 = new SPData
        {
            l = a,
            m = b,
            n = c,
            o = d
        };
        return spvalues22;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think in 2018 Microsoft has released the Async call for CSOM for Sharepoint online version.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/20472208-csom-net-async-support

There is a new method added stating

```
public method Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync
```

so first try to install this Nugat for Sharepoint Online or on-premises 2013 and 2016 then try to use Async Method.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-january-2018/

Hope on-premises also this new method will support though i could not verify dont have any Onprem environment right now.

Comment: What would one do in a situation where they are running SharePoint 2010 online and do not have access to the SharePoint server?

Comment: I did not get your question. but you should be knowing your SharePoint hosted Platform.either it would be SharePoint server or SharePoint online.To run CSOM code you dont need a Server Access but you need to have appropriate Permission in SharePoint site.

Comment: It is SharePoint online, but I receive errors anytime I try to use NuGet packages for anything > CSOM 2010.  That is what I was asking.